# Insert new data on embedded/nested Documents in mongodb

Tags: php, json, mongodb

What I'm trying to do is to insert new data on existing embedded documents with PHP. People have asked on SO about this but my case has more embedded documents, so I'm confused on how to do it. I have this JSON so far.

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7eb2eb57dce2fe0001280"),
    "name" : "CENTER-01",
    "data" : {
        "meter01" : {
            "magnitude01" : {
                "data" : "03/10/2012 11:09:47",
                "value" : 45
            },
```

And I want to add more data on `magnitude01`. So the JSON would be like:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7eb2eb57dce2fe0001280"),
    "name" : "CENTER-01",
    "data" : {
        "meter01" : {
            "magnitude01" : {
                "data" : "03/10/2012 11:09:47",
                "value" : 45
                "data" : "05/05/2013 12:38:45",
                "value" : 25
                "data" : "10/02/2015 16:45:12",
                "value" : 95
                "data" : "16/11/2017 15:12:32",
                "value" : 65
            },
```

If you realize, I'm adding more `data` and `value` to the document `magnitude01`. Although I don't know if it'd possible. However, I'm rather interested in how to add more data on it. (whatever the data would be)

I've tried several codes, and I EDITED with this one below because Ii think is the closest to the right one.

```
$id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5aa7eb2eb57dce2fe0001280');
$center->updateOne(
    ['_id' => $id],
    ['$push' => [array('data' => array('meter01' => array('magnitude01' => array(['data' : '03/10/2012 11:09:47', 'value' : 45 ]))))]]
);
```

I've spent a few hours looking for any solution, but I haven't been able to do it. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Ref Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986631/how-to-insert-new-data-in-an-embedded-document-in-mongodb

Comment: @FullStackTutorials It's exactly what I'm doing. However, that question in not as mine. My document has multiple documents nested, not only one. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: data.meter01.magnitude01 is not an array . Should be of the form `"data" : {         "meter01" : {             "magnitude01" : [{              "data" : "03/10/2012 11:09:47",                 "value" : 45             }]` to be able to use push modifier

Comment: @Veeram Thank you for your answer. I did what you told me. `['$push' => [array('data' => array('meter01' => array('magnitude01' => array(['data' : '03/10/2012 11:09:47', 'value' : 45 ]))))]]` not working.

Comment: Np.What error do you get ?  the change I mentioned has to be in done in db i.e to store magnitude01 values as array. Is that what you do ? You dont need to change your update statment

Comment: This is de error I get. `Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead`

Comment: You should be using below query after you made the magnitude01 an array field in database.
`$value = array("data" => "03/10/2012 11:09:47", "value" => 45);
$center->updateOne(
    ['_id' => $id],
    ['$push' => ['data.meter01.magnitude01' => $value]]
);`